# Definition of Measurable function

Tags: measure-theory

I have read two definition of measurable functions.

> (1)
>   A measurable function is the function that maps one set to another where pre-image of measurable subset is measurable
>
> (2)
>   If there is a sequence of step functions ${s_n} $ whose limit is $f$ almost everywhere in an interval $I$ then $f$ is Measurable function.

How can I relate these two definition?

Comment: The first definition is the canonical one, and you should try to internalize that in particular. The second one comes from the fact that the pointwise limit of measurable functions is a measurable function, proven using the first definition.

Comment: Sorry;I didn't get it@Chris

Comment: (1) is the standard definition, (2) is usually a theorem.